# Is a 2D object on a plane that gets curved still considered 2D or is it now 3D?

Tags: geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

Imagine a 2D square drawn on a flat membrane. The square has length and width, but no depth (obviously; it's a square). Now take said membrane and place it with the middle of the square centered atop some round object. Then press down on the membrane to curve it around said round object.

Would the square on the membrane still be considered two dimensional since it hasn't gained depth *relative to the membrane* or would it now be considered a 3D object since to an outside observer, the corners of the square - due to the curvature of the membrane - are now lower than the center of the square, thus technically giving the square depth relative to the round object?

Comment: Or, on further reflection, does the square - now that it's curved around the round object - cease being a square, since the definition of a square implies that it's flat, which it no longer is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of Dimension the letter D stands for. There are [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension).

1. The  [*topological dimension*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension) of the deformed square is still $2$, since it's homeomorphic to a part of a plane.
2. The *embedding dimension*, defined as the smallest $n$ such that the space has an isometric embedding into $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $2$ for the flat square but $3$ for the deformed square.